# How to get asp:hyperlink to display text instead of url

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a panel that gets a hyperlink added dynamiclly through C# with values from an sql database.

However some of the URLs are really long and quite uneccessary to display.

I have not found any good ways to hide/disable the url showing and replace it with text. I can not use normal `<a href>` as it handled server side.

EDIT added some of the code.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="moduleHyperlink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

now in C#

```
HyperLink hyp = createHyperlink(btn.link);
moduleHyperlink.Controls.Add(hyp);
```

This will display for the user the entire `btn.link` (url string) which might be really long and it looks messy on the webpage. I would rather have a text saying `"External Link"`, which when clicked redirects the user to the url.

Comment: post some code to understand what your issue is!!

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Is the problem that you get only the URL and not the site name from the database? Also, in what way would `<a href>` have been a solution if you could use it? I mean, what do you think `<a href>` can do that `<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl>` can't?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english/explaination. So i have displayed a hyperlink on my webpage. But what is shown is the url adress itself. Now if the url is really long and messy it doesnt look good. I would like to just have displayed a text like "External Link" that has attributes which when clicked sends the user to an other website (that url). This hyperlink is made on serverside in C#. Thats why i mentioned a href not beeing an option as i need to add the url in code behind.

Comment: `<asp:HyperLink ID="moduleHyperlink" runat="server">Youor Text Goes Here</asp:HyperLink>`

Comment: you can add `hyp.Text = <text>`

Comment: Thank you! I though that was the way. but i could not get it to work.So i figured i did it wrong. When revisiting the code i found another page that changed that hyperlink text to the url string AFTER my text change ><. Damn working with more people on same prosject xD

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Text` property to show some valid link title instead of showing the URL.

```
HyperLink hyp = createHyperlink(btn.link);
hyp.Text = "YourTextForTheLink";
moduleHyperlink.Controls.Add(hyp);`
```